# Transparent PNG div not showing on iOS devices

Tags: jquery, html, ios, css

I currently have a HTML page with a PNG image overlaying it with instruction on. When the page is clicked/touched the PNG disappears which is how I want it. However its the PNG image causing me issues as it shows up fine in safari but not on iOS devices. If anyone can help me I would be greatly appreciative.

HTML:

```
<div id="overlay">
 <img src="instructions V6.png" width="300" height="425" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#overlay {
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
position:absolute;
z-index: 1;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var overlay = $('#overlay');
    overlay.on('click', function (e) {
        overlay
            .hide()
            .off();
    });
});
```

Comment: space in the filename is probably causing this error

Comment: ios has a maximum file size it is able to load for png images - if they are too large they just don't bother.  Is the width and height you have shown the actual width and height of the original image or are you resizing it?

Comment: Hi Alex, I tried taking the space out but still not showing. The div with the dropped opacity is showing but just not the PNG inside it. Pete, that is the actual size of the image so not very big at all. That shouldn't be too big should it?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation on a website, where the image file would be squeezed into the dimensions but at full resolution. So you end up with a 300x425px box with nothing but black or transparency because the image is not being scaled.

Here are some possible fixed. iOS do not like shorthand notations for css so use

```
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
```

If it is the same issue as I had you can add a zoom, which often fixes the issue.

```
#overlay img{
zoom = 1;
}
```

Also there is a limit of 3mp or 3000x1000 resolution limit on files rendering on iOS. So make sure your image isn't too big for the iOS.

Hopefully that helps you out.

Comment: Hi Pazbi, I will give that a go now. Where do I add the Zoom element? To the CSS or the img source in HTML ?

Comment: Sorry, you apply it to the img, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Just tried your answer but still not working. Anything else you may think it might be?

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle or link?